# Cumulative Reports in salesforce

Tags: reporting

Can you please help with any references to create a report as Below.

[image]

Here, Cash Inflows/benefits, Cashoutflows/Costs are Rollup & Formula fields.

Kindly suggest , Shud i go for VF/ Can we achieve it by Reports

Thank you so much

Comment: What SF Objects hold the data in the above report?

Comment: Custom Objects- Benefits & Costs holds the data.
These two has lookup for Workrequest Object, Need to get the report of Lookup Fields, Please suggest shud i go for Reports / VF Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: reporting is all about data. You can only report on what you have. You're asking specifically about cash flows as used in bookkeeping.

In salesforce there is currently no stanard object to track that, however it's easy to (ab)use or extend something existing or create a few custom objects and a clean datamodel.

For instance you could use opportunities or orders at a specific state to monitor inflows, with negative amounts even outflows. IMO this isn't the very best approach but I've seen this pattern very often on client orgs. If you have a deal, cool thing with opps+orders are lineitems, products and pricebooks OTB and even schedules (for subscriptions/repetitions). But if your focus is cash and it's flow, I see it more as invoices and payments. Just imagine that you could charge many orders on one invoice and partial/incomplete payments, refunds etc.

I think salesforce is fine for cash flow, but way better with a handfull custom streamlined objects.

This said, if you have decided on which entities to be used as data sources, the grouping and rollup (first 4 of your lines) should be quite vanilla standard report functionality. There tons of videos and documentation on that:

- https://www.google.de/search?q=salesforce+reporting&num=100
- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_builder_editing.htm

I don't see the need of custom rollup summary fields unless you're creating your own custom lineitems.

Then you have a line with EPS and several lines in your second box. You need to figure again first the data sources and then the formulas. Whether you can use standard reports or VF+Apex is highly dependent on that. Standard reports have thier limits but if your  models+formulas aren't too complex use them.

Alternatively there also financial apps on appexchange.

An other wide spread approach is to integrate a third party ERP or financial system and mirror or display some data from it. Again you could use VF or standard reports.

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding the data schema it is speculation as to whether what I'm proposing would work in your situation but:

If you are summarizing line items or related opportunities/orders to a master object then you could do the first and second table through reports and as separate dashboard components with the date running vertically in dashboards.